# How can I insert a new column with data to a collection in MongoDB, through C#?

Tags: .net, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I have two fields that I should compare and take actions accordingly:

```
if(x == y) then x = [new Field called Z]
else [new Field called Z] = Math.Random
```

How can I do this in C# using MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supposing you have the following entity class `Item` defined as:

```
public class Item
{
    [BsonId]
    public String Id {get; set;}

    public int a {get; set;}

    public int x {get; set;}

    public int y {get; set;}
}
```

Using the **[MongoDB C# Driver](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-csharp-driver/)**, you could start by retrieving the two fields you want using **[`SetFields`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0.0/html/d49c0ba5-406d-5ae2-7ae9-e5c479461c10.htm)** method of **[`MongoCursor`](http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/2.0.0/html/65358efe-0d0d-a19b-a382-7f514e52c64a.htm)** class:

```
var server = MongoServer.Create(connectionString);
var db = server.GetDatabase("dbName");
MongoCollection collection = db.GetCollection<Item>("items");

MongoCursor<Item> cursor = collection.FindAs<Item>(Query.EQ("a", 33)); //if you want to match specific docs else Query.Null
cursor.SetFields(Fields.Include("x", "y"));
var items = cursor.ToList();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    // compare item.x and item.y and act accordingly
}
```

From here you can iterate through the cursor, do the comparison. If you want to do the update operation where you want to insert a new field `z` then this should work

```
collection.Update(Query.Null, Update.Set("z", Math.Random), UpdateFlags.Multi)
```

Comment: What does Items and DocType mean? I added MongoDB.Driver and Bson references but it couldn't find Items or Doctype, are they supposed to be user-defined?

Comment: Initially those were supposed to be the same, i.e. your user defined entity class, I quickly used them as an example but I have since updated my answer to include a more realistic example that you can follow clearly.